# Regex for the URL

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with writing the regex for the below URL?
I want a Regex to match the whole URL. The url format will be like this.

`https://www.mywebsite.com/us/cgi-bin/binary?cmd=_payment-option&transaction_id=8768JKHKJG19322&account_number=6UN85941RH525783L&transaction_date=Apr 12, 2012&transaction_amount=-$11.00&ccode=USD&act_id=6K6218756F7819322&counterparty=Pretty Flower Florist&initiated_page=_login&go_Ah9w8keNJ8YRLMkAMTS_Izeq0br1CF6OVtGv69WzOo8AjgDgGIiBetMG-lK&Go_Actions`

This is what I have got so far, but it is matching only till the first '&'

`http[s]*:\/\/www.[a-zA-Z0-9.]*mywebsite.[a-zA-Z]*[/]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*[/]*cgi-bin[/]*binary[?]*cmd=[_a-z\-]*[[\&][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[=][a-z ,A-Z0-9_-]*]*`

How can I repeat the pattern `&transaction_id=8768JKHKJG19322`?

`[[\&][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[=][a-z ,A-Z0-9_-]*]*` does not seem to work

Comment: You probably want to add what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

This is not very robust regex, but it should give you the idea - repeat common patterns.

```
http[s]?:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com(?:\/[a-zA-Z-?=_&\d\s,$\.]+)+
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer, because (as other posters have noted), it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, and what your context is.  If you just want to pull out the value of the query string parameter transaction_id, then this will do the job for you:

```
[&?]transaction_id=([^&]+)
```

In your OP, you have nested brackets.  Brackets are for character classes only; you can't nest them.

Instead, use parentheses.  Parentheses are used for two things: to indicate nesting or grouping, and to "capture" the value into the match[] array in your program.

As for recognizing the rest of the query string, you shouldn't have to match embedded spaces, as in your example `&counterparty=Pretty Flower Florist`; you should expect that spaces are encoded as + or %20.

**Update:**

This regex fragment will match the query string part of your input URLs:

```
([&?]([^=]+)(=([^&]+))?)*
```

It's not a precise restatement of the rules for query strings, but you can use it to capture parameter names and values.  This part

```
([^=]+)
```

captures the parameter name, and this part

```
([^&]+)
```

captures the parameter value, if any.

Comment: I want to write a regex to match string like `&transaction_id=8768JKHKJG19322` .There will be many repeating fields like this. &par1=value1&par2=value2&par3=value3. So a single regex to match repeating pattern is what I am looking for.